# PHP [PDO] Login Script Acting Up

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, password-hash

I do like PHP but sometimes it's really annoying.

I have a login script here:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("include/database.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $errMsg = '';
    //username and password sent from Form
    $username = $_POST['user_login'];
    $password = $_POST['user_password'];

    if ($username == '') {
        $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';
    }

    if ($password == '') {
        $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';
    }


    if ($errMsg == '') {
        $records = $db->prepare('SELECT user_id ,user_login ,user_password FROM users WHERE user_login = :username');
        $records->bindParam(':username', $username  );
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['user_password'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_login'] = $results['user_login'];
            header('location:test.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But everytime I try to log in, it fails me. and pops an error message at the bottom.

I have my passwords hashed so I don't see the problem in *password_verify*

My *users* table follows this setup:

Table Layout

[image]

The trick is, if I remove *password_verify* my code works but it doesn't check if the user exists and passes any values over that page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `user_password` => `varchar(42)` - there's your problem. Needs to be **at least** 60 length (you can just use a 255 length). From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php): "*..Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).*" -- when you now update the length of the column, all the passwords needs to be re-hashed and updated into the database.

Comment: ^ where I suspected from the start and closed it as per a recent answer of mine for another question with the same problem.

Comment: user_password varchar(42) => `user_password varchar(255)`

Comment: In the end, the problem wasn't just the size of the attribute.
I also used a different hash.